# Switching from Postmark to Postfix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

We want to switch from Postmark to Postfix, but with Postfix the mail with the attachment(PDF file) is arriving as garbage:

```
Date: Sun, 10 Apr 2016 13:17:56 +0300 
Mime-Version: 1.0 
Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=UTF-8; filename=test_order1460278254278.pdf 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test_order1460278254278.pdf 
Content-ID: <570a2854317a9_1c6f12f77f841854@app1.mail> 
JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKNSAwIG9iago8PC9CYXNlRm9udC9QV1dNR1QrQXJp 
YWxNVC9EZXNjZW5kYW50Rm9udHNbNiAwIFJdL1R5cGUvRm9udC9TdWJ0eXBl 
L1R5cGUwL0VuY29kaW5nL0lkZW50aXR5LUgvVG9Vbmljb2RlIDkgMCBSPj4K 
ZW5kb2JqCjEwIDAgb2JqCjw8L0Jhc2VGb250L1dYSkRSSytMdWNpZGFTYW5z 
LVR5cGV3cml0ZXJCb2xkL0Rlc2NlbmRhbnRGb250c1sxMSAwIFJdL1R5cGUv 
Rm9udC9TdWJ0eXBlL1R5cGUwL0VuY29kaW5nL0lkZW50aXR5LUgvVG9Vbmlj 
b2RlIDE0IDAgUj4+CmVuZG9iagoxNSAwIG9iago8PC9CYXNlRm9udC9UaW1l
```

This is my code:

```rb
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "mailer@xodapp1.com"
  default :bcc => "do_not_reply@xodapp1.com"
  default :reply_to => "do_not_reply@xodapp1.com"

  def send_email(agent, customer, subject, body, mail_to = nil, mail_cc = nil, url_attachment = nil , name_attachment = nil)
    #attachments[name_attachment] = {:content => open(url_attachment).read, :mime_type =>  MIME::Types.type_for(name_attachment).first}  unless url_attachment.nil?
    mail_to = !mail_to.nil? ?  mail_to : "\"#{customer.name}\" <#{customer.email}>"
    mailers_to = mail_to.split(',')

    mail_cc = !mail_cc.nil? ?  mail_cc.split(',') : agent.email
    if [nil, []].include?(mail_cc)
      mail_cc = UserMailer.default[:bcc]
    end

    body = "Copy attached" if body.nil? || body.empty?

    mail_obj = mail(:to => mailers_to,
         :from => "\"#{agent.name}\" <mailer@xodapp1.com>",
         :bcc =>  mail_cc,
         :subject => subject,
         :content_type => "text/html",
         :body => body.html_safe,
         :reply_to => "#{!agent.email.nil? ? agent.email : UserMailer.default[:reply_to]}"
    )
    mail_obj.attachments[name_attachment] =  open(url_attachment).read unless url_attachment.nil?
    return mail_obj
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I remove the content_type and change the order:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "mailer@cavsystems.com"
  default :bcc => "do_not_reply@cavsystems.com"
  default :reply_to => "do_not_reply@cavsystems.com"

  def send_email(agent, customer, subject, body, mail_to = nil, mail_cc = nil, url_attachment = nil , name_attachment = nil)
    #attachments[name_attachment] = {:content => open(url_attachment).read, :mime_type =>  MIME::Types.type_for(name_attachment).first}  unless url_attachment.nil?
    mail_to = !mail_to.nil? ?  mail_to : "\"#{customer.name}\" <#{customer.email}>"
    mailers_to = mail_to.split(',')

    mail_cc = !mail_cc.nil? ?  mail_cc.split(',') : agent.email
    if [nil, []].include?(mail_cc)
      mail_cc = UserMailer.default[:bcc]
    end

    body = "Copy attached" if body.nil? || body.empty?

    attachments[name_attachment] =  open(url_attachment).read unless url_attachment.nil?
    mail(:to => mailers_to,
         :from => "\"#{agent.name}\" <mailer@cavsystems.com>",
         :bcc =>  mail_cc,
         :subject => subject,
         #:content_type => "text/html",
         :body => body.html_safe,
         :reply_to => "#{!agent.email.nil? ? agent.email : UserMailer.default[:reply_to]}"
    )
    #mail_obj.attachments[name_attachment] =  open(url_attachment).read unless url_attachment.nil?
    #return mail_obj
  end
end
```

Now the email is arriving with the pdf attachment but the HTML code is raw :-(
It's o.k. because we need the pdf not the html.

It will be great if the HTML will be visible.